# Soasta touch test Performance engineering , how to get the CPU/memory usage of a mobile application?

Tags: cpu

Using Soasta test , I need to know how to measure the CPU usage of any specific  mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

In SOASTA TouchTest, CPU (and memory, battery, IO) are measured during the test and displayed in the results dashboards.

[TouchTest device stats widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpwyi.png)